# Using serializeArray() on form input and echo it?

Tags: php, json, ajax, forms

I want the user to input their name and email address, and then have it echo on the page after they hit "submit" on the form. The problem is, when I hit submit, the "email _address" and "name" is not found in my ajax2.php. Im sure i'm using the wrong syntax but I can't figure out what to change.

**My form:**

```
        <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>      
        <input type="text" id="email_address">

        <label for="name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">


        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <button type='submit'>submit</button>

</form>
```

**Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#email_form").submit(function(){
                 event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "include/ajax2.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $("#email_form").serializeArray(),
                    success: function(data){
                       var assArr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        $("#output").html("Email:" +assArr['email_address'] + " Name:" + assArr['name']);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        $("#output").html("Error with ajax");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

**ajax2.php**

```
$assocArr = array();
$assocArr ['email_address'] = $_POST['email_address'];
$assocArr ['name'] = $_POST['name'];

echo json_encode($assocArr);
```

Comment: Try adding `name='email_address'` and such on your inputs. If it works I'll write a slightly fuller answer.

Comment: You need to put `<input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">` and `<input type="text" id="name" name="name">`

Comment: As the comments above point out, form fields are only submitted to the server (in a normal postback) or serialised (via jQuery's form serialisation methods) if they have a "name" attribute in the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, add "dataType:json" to the request:

Add name of the elements: email_address and name:

```
<form id="email_form" name="email_form" >
  <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>      
  <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
  <label for="name">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
   <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Add "dataType:json":

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#email_form").submit(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "include/ajax2.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: $("#email_form").serializeArray(),
            success: function (data) {
                var assArr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#output").html("Email:" + assArr['email_address'] + " Name:" + assArr['name']);
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#output").html("Error with ajax");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The file ajax2.php does not change:

```
$assocArr = array();
$assocArr ['email_address'] = $_POST['email_address'];
$assocArr ['name'] = $_POST['name'];
echo json_encode($assocArr);
```

File ajax2.php will return:

```
{"email_address":"JohnDoe@gmail.com","name":"John Doe"}
```